# Read the file faster and get the pixel color quickly?

Tags: c#, file, file-io, streamreader, streamwriter

I've got the following code and it works properly, however, it works really slowly and to read the file with the recording and analyze each pixel - it takes way too long. Is there any way I could make it work faster?

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern Int32 ReleaseDC(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hdc);
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
static extern uint GetPixel(IntPtr hdc, int nXPos, int nYPos);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (isCorrect("test.LOB"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Yes");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Nope...");
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
    //Record("test", 0, 0, 50, 50, 10);
}

public static void Record(string name, int start_x, int start_y, int end_x, int end_y, int max_Difference)
{
    string path = name + ".LOB";
    string result;
    Color pixel_Result;
    for (int x = start_x; x <= end_x; x++)
    {
        for (int y = start_y; y <= end_y; y++)
        {
            pixel_Result = GetPixelColor(x, y);
            result = x + "|" + y + "|" + pixel_Result.R + "|" + pixel_Result.G + "|" + pixel_Result.B + "|" + max_Difference;
            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(result);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(result);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static bool isCorrect(string path)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
    {
        string result = "";
        string[] correctedResult;
        while ((result = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            correctedResult = result.Split('|');
            int X = Convert.ToInt32(correctedResult[0]);
            int Y = Convert.ToInt32(correctedResult[1]);
            int R = Convert.ToInt32(correctedResult[2]);
            int G = Convert.ToInt32(correctedResult[3]);
            int B = Convert.ToInt32(correctedResult[4]);
            int maxDifference = Convert.ToInt32(correctedResult[5]);
            Color c;
            c = GetPixelColor(X, Y);
            maxDifference /= 2;
            if (R < c.R - maxDifference || R > c.R + maxDifference)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (G < c.G - maxDifference || G > c.G + maxDifference)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (B < c.B - maxDifference || B > c.B + maxDifference)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}

static public Color GetPixelColor(int x, int y)
{
    IntPtr hdc = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
    uint pixel = GetPixel(hdc, x, y);
    ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, hdc);
    Color color = Color.FromArgb((int)(pixel & 0x000000FF),
                 (int)(pixel & 0x0000FF00) >> 8,
                 (int)(pixel & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
    return color;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok without going into unsafe methods, right off the bat I see you are logging every loop! On top of that you are creating a new streamwriter every time.

Comment: Can you show us `GetDC`, `GetPixel`, and `ReleaseDC`

Comment: I tried including it in the code above, but it kept breaking the post for some reason...

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern Int32 ReleaseDC(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hdc);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        static extern uint GetPixel(IntPtr hdc, int nXPos, int nYPos);

Comment: Damn, let me try again.

Comment: You need to highlight the text and click the button `{ }` on the toolbar of your post. You can't put code in comments.

Comment: It worked this time, when I tried it before - it would break the code when I was trying to post it.

Comment: One thought: Don't `GetDC`/`ReleaseDC` for every pixel. Instead, call `GetDC` once before your loop and call `ReleaseDC` once after your loop. Pass the HDC as an argument into your `GetPixelColor` function.

Comment: @MichaelGunter does that look any better? https://pastebin.com/00FCvRGi

Comment: Site blocked by my corporate firewall. I'll leave it to you to make the changes, verify that your algorithm still works, and test the performance.

Comment: @PSawicki use gist.github.com it is less likey to be blocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two major issues slowing down your code. First, you open and close your stream writer every pixel, this is going to be very slow. Move the opening to outside of the loop. Also there is a constructor of `StreamWriter` that lets you specifiy append mode so you don't need your if/else check.

The 2nd problem is you are opening and closing your IntPtr handle every pixel too, this is going to be very slow, open it once then close it when you are done.

```
static public Color GetPixelColor(int x, int y, IntPtr hdc)
{
    uint pixel = GetPixel(hdc, x, y);
    Color color = Color.FromArgb((int)(pixel & 0x000000FF),
                 (int)(pixel & 0x0000FF00) >> 8,
                 (int)(pixel & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
    return color;
}

public static bool isCorrect(string path)
{
    IntPtr hdc = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
    try
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
        {
            string result = "";
            string[] correctedResult;
            while ((result = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                correctedResult = result.Split('|');
                int X = Convert.ToInt32(correctedResult[0]);
                int Y = Convert.ToInt32(correctedResult[1]);
                int R = Convert.ToInt32(correctedResult[2]);
                int G = Convert.ToInt32(correctedResult[3]);
                int B = Convert.ToInt32(correctedResult[4]);
                int maxDifference = Convert.ToInt32(correctedResult[5]);
                Color c;
                c = GetPixelColor(X, Y, hdc);
                maxDifference /= 2;
                if (R < c.R - maxDifference || R > c.R + maxDifference)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                if (G < c.G - maxDifference || G > c.G + maxDifference)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                if (B < c.B - maxDifference || B > c.B + maxDifference)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, hdc);
    }
}

public static void Record(string name, int start_x, int start_y, int end_x, int end_y, int max_Difference)
{
    string path = name + ".LOB";

    string result;
    Color pixel_Result;

    IntPtr hdc = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
    try
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, append:true))
        {
            for (int x = start_x; x <= end_x; x++)
            {
                for (int y = start_y; y <= end_y; y++)
                {
                    pixel_Result = GetPixelColor(x, y, hdc);
                    result = x + "|" + y + "|" + pixel_Result.R + "|" + pixel_Result.G + "|" + pixel_Result.B + "|" + max_Difference;
                    sw.WriteLine(result);
                }
            }
        }
    finally
    {
        ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, hdc);
    }
}
```

If after fixing the slowness in GetPixelColor the code is still too slow I would recommend running a profiler on the code to see which part is the slowness coming from, you may be able to pipeline the work with some tools like [TPL DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) so the reading of the pixels are single threaded but you use multiple threads to test the read values to see if they are correct or not.

Comment: I've already got the following code: 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fac075a4cfdf5d3532c5708ea34660da
Is there anything I should change? // I just realized I made a mistake, sorry, don't look at that

Comment: I would put the release in a try/finally block instead of before every return, then you only need to write it once and if a exception is thrown it still gets released.

Comment: That's the one I have right now: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8eeb2833960efa243d022c283d47369f

Comment: Looks ok, can't tell without running it. If it is still too slow run a profiler on the code and see where it is taking the most time. If you find the string to int conversions being the slow part and you don't need the .LOB file to be human readable storing the values using a `BinaryWriter` and `BinaryReader` to read it back may be faster because it does not need to do that conversion from a string in to a int. You could even skip the `Color.FromArgb` call and just write and read the raw `uint pixel` values to the file. then do the conversion to a `Color` object when you do your test.

Comment: If i write the raw uint pixel, it will still be needed to convert later, so it doesn't matter to me. The code you gave me works definitely faster, however, I'm not too sure how to use the 'BinaryWriter' and Reader to make it work even faster.

Comment: Here is a example using a BinaryWriter, however do note I wrote this in a web browser, so there could be errors in the code. https://gist.github.com/leftler/4b12802f0bbe61e990ed6d0762256c52

Comment: the 'totalCount' variable doesn't exist in Record, what was it supposed to be?

Comment: It seems to be working way slower than the method we used before